# Laravel 5 product order relation syntax: Not unique table/alias

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, syntax-error, relationship

I'm working on an applications which can be used to make pricelist orders for products.
**In short**: a restaurant has a pricelist, which they can update by following a flow where they can insert new prices.

As result a price order will be generated.

Now what I want is that I **retrieve all categories with products** (no problem) and then I want to make a **relation from product to the PriceOrderProduct** so I know when a product is used in an order.

I have this now:

```
ProductCategory::with('products.orderProduct')->orderBy('order')->get()
```

which gaves me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:
```

complete error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'price_order_products' (SQL: select `price_order_products`.*, `price_order_products`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `price_order_products`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `price_order_products` inner join `price_order_products` on `price_order_products`.`id` = `price_order_products`.`id` where `price_order_products`.`product_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11))
```

I have searched for this error, but don't know how to fix, can someone help me out with this issue?

### These are my tables and relations:

(I make use of a `price_` prefix for my tables)

**Table: price_product_categories**
- id
category info etc.

**Model: ProductCategory**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_category_id');
}
```

==========================
**price_products**
- id
- product_category_id
product info etc.

**Model: Product**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 'product_category_id');
}


public function orderProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(PriceOrderProduct::class, 'price_order_products', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

==========================
**Table: price_orders**
- id
- restaurant_id
etc.

**Model: PriceOrder**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PriceOrderProduct::class, 'order_id');
}
```

==========================
**Table price_order_products**
- order_id
- product_id
- price
- product_info

**Model: PriceOrderProduct**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PriceOrder::class);
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id', 'product_id');
}
```

Comment: I think you got confused on the relationships. your have `Product->belongsTo` when Product should be your beacon class, meaning it  should own `category` and `not be owned by a category`

Comment: Also your DB structure can be built differently and accomodate future changes, but it depends on where your products are growing. For instance, would you recon your product only owns 1 type of category? Or is it probable they can own one or more categories? If latest rings a bell and a future possibility, then I would highly recommend to restructure your models and database relationships where a `Product` can own `one or more` Categories` which will present you with a one to many relationships that in this case will result in 3 tables just for `Product` and `Categories` relationship;

Comment: On the other hand, could you elaborate why the need for `PriceOrderProduct` and `PriceOrder`? Also they could be better named imho, to quickly settled the objective of the tables and their relationships :) I will be able to help out more after I set this into stone

Comment: @DiogoSanto I refactored some of my eloquent models and database tablenames. Now it is better to read the relations. Also Peter had the solution for me. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'price_products';

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 'product_category_id');
    }

    public function orderProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PriceOrderProduct::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

This will work for your query for the desired output. By getting a hasMany relation and not a belongsToMany.

Comment: the hasMany did the job! Thanks!